# Problem adding ordered lists dynamically to bootstrap slider

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In reference to the bootstrap slider on [w3schools here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) I am trying to have the slider to work without having to manually add the ordered lists.

HTML:

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/google.jpeg">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/google.jpeg">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/google.jpeg">
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var numSlides = $('.item').length;

setTimeout(function(){

  $("<ol class='carousel-indicators'></ol>").insertBefore('.carousel-inner');


  for(i = 1; i <= numSlides; i++) {
    $("<li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to=''+ i + ''></li>").appendTo('.carousel-indicators');
  }

  $('.carousel-indicators > li:first-child').addClass('active');
}, 1000);
```

When I load the page, the content actually slides, but I notice that the indicators are not working when I click on them, neither highlight when a slide changes.

How can I adapt the bootstrap slider according to my needs?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/rNVjebd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have typos in your code so the html code you add isn't correct.
I think the for loop should like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < numSlides; i++) {
    $("<li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='" + i + "'></li>").appendTo('.carousel-indicators');
}
```

I changed `data-slide-to=''+ i + ''` to `data-slide-to='" + i + "'` and `i` should start from 0

Hope this help.

Comment: It did not make a difference. Have you tried via the codepen perhaps?

Comment: Oh sorry, I think you need to update the `i` value in for loop too, I'll update the answer

Comment: You were right about the for loop. It has to start at 0. Also, I noticed that I had to remove the setTimeout.
Appreciate the support.